# How to see if a button input matches a value from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to programming, but I had a a few questions, I am building a word guessing game, and when a player click a button on the game keyboard, the empty boxes will reveal all the instances of the letters that match below is a picture:

[word guessing game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNb6I.png)

this is the array I have:

```
const phrases = ["life is strange","success does not come easy", "seven swans swimming", "guess the word", "wild goose chase"]
```

In this method, I am trying to iterate the array to get the first letter of each phrase, and if there is indeed a match when someone clicks a button from the keyboard, *checkLetter* needs to return true and I will call another method called *showMatchedLetter()*

```
checkLetter() {
    for (var i=0; i < phrases.length; i++) {
        console.log(phrases[i].charAt(0) );
        return true
    }
 }
```

if the previous method returns true, then this method will be called upon to reveal the letter in the game

```
showMatchedLetter() {
//if there was a match on the checkLetter method, then add a show letter class to the lis items
    if (checkLetter === true) {
        newListItem.className = 'show letter';
    }


}
```

this is the html for the keyboard
[Keyboard HTMl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnlv6.png)

the idea is that I have to make the empty boxes reveal all the instances of a letter if a player guesses right, could someone please help?

Comment: UPDATE: I added more details of what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

The issue from what I can tell is that you're trying to use a reference to a div as the comparison value. It won't actually provide you with a value the buttons are meant to represent like this. I would recommend changing showMatchedLetter to take in a parameter for the letter, and then for each of your buttons giving them a onclick call to that function passing in the letter it represents. Something like:

```
<button class="key" onclick="showMatchedLetter('q');">q</button>
<button class="key" onclick="showMatchedLetter('w');">w</button>
<button class="key" onclick="showMatchedLetter('e');">e</button>
<button class="key" onclick="showMatchedLetter('r');">r</button>
<button class="key" onclick="showMatchedLetter('t');">t</button>
<button class="key" onclick="showMatchedLetter('y');">y</button>
//etc...
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however I have updated my question